# Extracting a string within a string between "[" and "]"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, power-bi-report-server

I'm trying to extract a portion of a string. The string I want always begins with "[reportserver". I want to extract everything after that until the next "]" The text after "[reportserver" to "]" could be varied. Here is the entire string:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Schedule_UpdateExpiration] 
            ON [dbo].[Schedule] AFTER UPDATE  
AS
UPDATE EC
SET AbsoluteExpiration = I.NextRunTime 
FROM [reportserver - EMPTYTempDB].dbo.ExecutionCache AS EC
INNER JOIN ReportSchedule AS RS ON EC.ReportID = RS.ReportID
INNER JOIN inserted AS I ON RS.ScheduleID = I.ScheduleID AND RS.ReportAction = 3
```

In this case I want to extract: "reportserver - EMPTYTempDB"

I've come close with this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@TEXT,CHARINDEX('[reportserver',@TEXT)+1,(CHARINDEX(']',@TEXT)))
```

Which returns: "reportserver - EMPTYTe" . Close, but no cigar. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upvoted the other answer because it's correct, but just a slightly different way to look at it - I like to use a CTE to pass down things like `CHARINDEX` so the code only has to include them once.

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT t = @text, c = CHARINDEX(N'[reportserver', @text)
),
y AS 
(
  SELECT r = SUBSTRING(t,c,4000) FROM x
),
z AS 
(
  SELECT o = LEFT(r, CHARINDEX(N']', r)) FROM y
)
SELECT o FROM z;
```

The nice thing about this approach (other than avoiding repeating any expression multiple times) is the ability to easily inspect the outcome of any CTE.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=e145007d02805d54d7d798fbcf34e2b6)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen hahaha

Answer (score 2):

The following logic is working:

```sql
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(val,
              CHARINDEX('[reportserver', val) + 1,
              CHARINDEX(']', val, CHARINDEX('[reportserver', val)) - CHARINDEX('[reportserver', val) - 1) AS output
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

Your first and second inputs into `SUBSTRING` were correct, but the third parameter needs to be the length of the substring to take.  This is basically the difference between the position of the `]` immediately following the `[` in `[reportserver`, and the position of the latter.